# Ag-grid custom cell editor not returning correct state

Tags: ag-grid-react

We're using ag-grid version 21 and trying to add a custom cell editor to the grid.  However in the useImperativeHandle's getValue, the state value is coming blank all the time.  What could be the issue please?

```
const CustomEditor = forwardRef((props,ref)=>{
    const [value,setValue] = useState('');
    const inputRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(()=>{
        inputRef.current.focus();
        inputRef.current.select();
    },[]);

    useImperativeHandle(ref,()=>{
        return {
            getValue: () => {
                return value; //this returns '' everytime
            },
            afterGuiAttached: () => {
                setValue('hello');
                inputRef.current.focus();
                inputRef.current.select();
            },
            isCancelBeforeStart: ()=>false
        }
    });

    return (
        <input type="text"
        value={value}
        ref={inputRef}
        onChange={(e)=>setValue(e.target.value)}
        />
    );
});
```

The parent component App.js

```
const columns = useMemo(()=> {
return [
   { field: "id",headerName: "ID"},
   { field: "userInput", editable: true, cellEditor: "customEditor"}
],[]);
<AgGrid
columnDefs={columns}
rowData={rows}
frameworkComponents={{
  customEditor: CustomEditor
}}
/>
```